# What is the term for substituting a context-specific word into a well-known phrase?

Tags: terminology

What is the term for substituting a context-specific word into a well-known phrase?

For example, there's a saying like "Actions speak louder than words". So I'll, for example, substitute the word "Actions" with "Lowering taxes", so it would look like this: "Lowering taxes speaks louder than words".
The context would be that the government has promised some time ago than it would lower the taxes, but it didn't, so some person criticizes it with the aforementioned sentence.

Comment: [Snowclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is ‘about the English language in general, not just as it relates to literature or specific works’

Answer (score 1):

As [@Gareth Rees](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16642/what-is-the-term-for-substituting-a-context-specific-word-into-a-well-known-phra#comment25983_16642) says in the comments, this is an example of a [snowclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone), a

> linguistic phenomenon of "a multi-use, customizable, instantly recognizable, time-worn, quoted or misquoted phrase or sentence that can be used in an entirely open array of different variants"

Some of the examples given are "In space, no one can hear you X" and "X is the new Y". These are such well-known sentence structures that no matter what words go in the blanks, the reference and meaning is immediately understandable.

You seem to be using the well-known phrase "X speak louder than words" as a snowclone. At least I understood the reference immediately, so it worked for me. I'm not sure if there is a word for the *act* of making/using a snowclone, other than "using a snowclone".